# How to receive Parcelable object parameters in separate activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I would like to be able to receive the individual parameters of my paracable object in the next activity. I believe that I am using the correct method, just do not understand how to output the parameter inputs once in the second activity.

My MainActivty.kt:

```
package com.example.favouritefood

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val food1: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFood1)
        val food2: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFood2)
        val food3: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFood3)
        val food4: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFood4)

        val pizza = Food(
                "Pizza", "www.test.com", "Italy, Tomato",
                "1/1/2018", "pizza@mail.com", 5)

        food1.setOnClickListener()
        {
            val intent = Intent(this, MetaDataActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("Food", pizza)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

My second activity (to receive the parcelable):

```
package com.example.favouritefood

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.widget.EditText

class MetaDataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meta_data)

        val name: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextName)

        val food = intent.getParcelableExtra("Food") as Parcelable

        val test = food.writeToParcel(food, 0)

        name.setText(test.toString())
    }
}
```

Where `food.wrtieToParcel(food, 0)` throws a type mismatch of Required: Parcel! Found: Parcelable over `food`.

How would I go about reading the parameters in the object?

My object class for reference:

```
package com.example.favouritefood

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

class Food(val name: String?, val location: String?, val keywords: String?, val date: String?, val email: String?, val rating: Int) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readInt()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeString(location)
        parcel.writeString(keywords)
        parcel.writeString(date)
        parcel.writeString(email)
        parcel.writeInt(rating)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Food> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Food {
            return Food(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Food?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `val test = food.writeToParcel(food, 0)`.

use `val food =  intent.getParcelableExtra("Food") as Food` instead.

Comment: And then how would I set the Edit Text `name` to the first parameter of the Pizza object (which is `Pizza`)? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: name.setText(food.getName())